# How to understand if an input sentence has a negative or a positive meaning?

Tags: java, nlp

I am doing a project in Java, and I am looking for some open-source/tool that will given a sentence return if the sentence has a negative or a positive meaning.

For example:

1. I have a problem-Negative.
2. I don't have a problem-Positive.
3. I have a working connection-Positive

Does such tool exist?

Comment: What do you feel when you ask if such a tool exists?

Comment: I don't think I cannot say you are wrong...

Comment: I am not talking about crazy sentences with sarcasm and 7 different negatives. Something a little more basic.

Comment: Apparently too basic, IMHO. How is, for instance, "I have a problem." negative? Do you think, for instance, that "I do not have the slightest problems with alcohol." is positive, even if uttered by a well known alcoholic?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of a tool that will do this particular task. I believe most of them are tight to specific needs and won't be easily portable. However, one way of doing it will be to have your set of positive and negative words predefined. Then, given an input sentence count the positive and negative words in it and whichever number is greater, this will be your conclusion. Check here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentiment_analysis . This thread may be of help too: [Algorithm to determine how positive or negative a statement/text is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293000/algorithm-to-determine-how-positive-or-negative-a-statement-text-is)

Comment: `Then, given an input sentence count the positive and negative words in it and whichever number is greater, this will be your conclusion.` isn't this a bit too naive? Let's say: "problem" is a negative word, then how about `It worked out without the slightest problems.`

Comment: Its not naive. A lot of sentiment analysis tools work with similar ideas in mind. "It worked out without the slightest problems" is a difficult challenge that cannot be easily solved :) I just tried to give the guy some directions.

Comment: Maybe it's not naive. Maybe it's a clever trick of the marketing industry to get people to pay more for placing advertising on pages with alledgedly "positive" sentiments. After all, the computer says it's 87% positive sentiment, therefore it must be true, right?

Comment: I dont get the point you are trying to make :) I dont think it is relevant to the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

I can not imagine that such a tool exists. (Because that would mean to recognize Sarcasm, and I know this was some research topic.)

Comment: A tool may exists, yet if it's reliable is another question.

Comment: @Ingo: Is that (your comment) a positive or negative sentence?

Comment: depends on whether you count sceptizism as positive or negative. :) This is, IMHO, the main question in this issue: apparently it is thought that "positive" and "negative" are givens.

Comment: Don't let the perfect get in the way of the good.  Surely there are no tools that get it 100% correct, but you can reasonably easily get to 80% accuracy for review data.

Comment: How do you measure accuracy of figures about sentiments?

Comment: Ask humans to label a sample of data.  See how often the machine agrees with the human.

Answer (score 1):

You could get started with the basic ideas of [Eliza](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA) there is also a [java implementation](http://www.chayden.net/eliza/Eliza.html)  it does primitive natural language processing.

Answer (score 0):

I find this question overly simplistic. For over a decade, entire teams of researchers have been trying to identify sentiment in text. Even the simplest sentences are often difficult, and are highly context-dependent. For example

> Read the book.

is a positive sentence if it appears in a book review. The same sentence is negative if it appears in a movie review. As Ingo points out, simply counting positive/negative words will not work out at all. The placement of negators in the parse-tree of the sentence matters, and as my example shows, there are many sentences with no positive/negative words, but different sentiment polarities in different contexts. Here's another example off the top of my head

> The crazy movie held its audience captive.

but,

> The crazy king held the peasants captive.