# train LUIS to understand the difference between "I am interested" and "I am not interested"

Tags: nlp, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have a scenario where I have to train LUIS models to understand the difference between "I am interested" and "I am not interested". How to achieve it without directly mentioning the utterances in Intents.

Comment: not possible right now. you can follow this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293000/algorithm-to-determine-how-positive-or-negative-a-statement-text-is

Answer (score 0):

You can try using another cognitive service endpoint to detect `sentiment`. Take a look: http://www.pveller.com/smarter-conversations-part-1-sentiment/

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about [Sentiment Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentiment_analysis). To my understanding, it is not possible to train LUIS models to decipher positive or negative sentiments without training *positive and negative* intents. As Pavel indicates there is another Microsoft offered service, the [Text Analytics API](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/text-analytics-api).

This API provides multiple services, but in this case will take your provided string(s), measure the sentiment, and return the measurements (by `id`) as a number between 0 and 1. Numbers closer to 0 are more negative than those closer to 1. The greater the number, the more positive the string is. To include Text Analytics, I've used a `Promise` for the API call:

```
let sentimentAnalysis = function (string) {
    let payload = {
        "documents": [{
            "id": "1",
            "text": string ? string : 'No string? This is sad...'
        }]
    }

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request.post(
        'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/sentiment/', 
            {
                "headers": {
                    "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": process.env.TEXT_ANALYTICS_KEY,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                },
                "body": JSON.stringify(payload)
            }, (err, res, body) => {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                } else {
                    return resolve(JSON.parse(res.body));
                }
            }
        )
    })
}
```

Note that the payload contains a `"documents"` property which takes an array of objects. You can either pass in entire paragraphs or narrow it down to separating sentence by sentence. However, I will leave that decision (and design) up to you :)

The official statement however, does say that splitting the strings down to sentences will improve the sentiment analysis ([response to the comments by Lowellkitchen on 2016.12.9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-text-analytics-quick-start#comments-container)).

Inside of my waterfall, I'll call this `Promise` and use the result to determine the response of my chatbot.

```
sentimentAnalysis(results.response).then(analyticsResponse => {
    session.send(`You said "${results.response}"!`);
    let score = Math.round(analyticsResponse["documents"][0]["score"] * 100) / 100;
    session.send(`The score of that utterance is ${score}`);
    if(score > 0.7) {
        session.endDialog("Wow that's positive!");
    } else if (score > 0.4) {
        session.endDialog("Wow that's neutral-ish...");
    } else {
        session.endDialog("Wow that is not positive.");
    }
})
```

[GitHub](https://github.com/stevengum97/SO_Q43321041)